# What matrix corresponds to the sum of the column space of two matrices? [Strang P131 3.1.31]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $P124:$ The column space consists of all linear combinations of the columns. The combinations are all possible vectors $\mathbf{Ax}$ and fill $C(A)$.
>
> The columns of $A$ and $B$ and $M$ are all in $\mathbb{R^m}.$ Then $colspace(A) + colspace(B)$ is column space of what matrix $M$? (I don't think $\color{green}{A + B}$ is
>   always a correct $M$.)
>
> Brusque Answer : $colspace(A) + colspace(B)$ is the column space of $M = \begin{bmatrix}
>     A & B 
>     \end{bmatrix}$.

Say $A$ has $\alpha$ columns and $B$ has $\beta$. In view of the answer, I see : 
$colspace(M) = \sum_{1 \le i \le \alpha + \beta}k_i\cdot\text{column $i$ of M} $
$= \sum_{1 \; \le \; i  \; \le \; \alpha}k_i\cdot\text{column $i$ of A} + \sum_{\alpha + 1 \; \le \; i \; \le \; \alpha + \beta}k_i\cdot\text{column $j$ of B} \quad $ for all $k_i \in \mathbb{C}$. 
$= colspace(A) + colspace(B) $.

$\Large{{1.}}$ Would someone please explain how to compute/determine: $M = \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B 
    \end{bmatrix}$?

$\Large{{2.}}$ Does the answer's $M$ comprise $\color{green}{A + B}$ which the question referred to?
The question didn't expound or uncloak why $A + B$ can be wrong?

**[Official Solution (cp Problem Set 3)](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/psets.shtml)**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, perhaps you could elaborate on which part of the proof you do not understand?

For the second one, here's a simple counter-example: let $A$ be some non-zero matrix, and let $B = -A$. Then $$\mathrm{colspace}(A) = \mathrm{colspace}(B),$$and $$\mathrm{colspace}(A) + \mathrm{colspace}(B) = \mathrm{colspace}(A) \not= \{0\},$$but $$\mathrm{colspace}(A+B) = \mathrm{colspace}(\mathrm{zero matrix}) = \{0\}.$$

Comment: +1. Thank you. As regards the first question, I simply don't see from where $ M = \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B 
    \end{bmatrix}$ is derived?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Well, $M$ is just a really good guess at what such a matrix should look like. There are plenty of other matrices with the same column space. For instance, $[\begin{matrix} -A & B \end{matrix}]$ or $[\begin{matrix} A & A & B \end{matrix}]$ would also work.