# Linear combination of vectors with norming term to be a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, vector-analysis

For two real vectors $X_1$ and $X_2$, by "linear combination", we mean $aX_1 + bX_2$ for any $a$ and $b$. We use this term while defining vector spaces and related things.

Is there any standard name for such combination: $AX_1  + BX_2$, where $A$ and $B$ are real matrices? Like "Linear matrix combination"? Is there any standard literature where people have investigated the properties of such combination?

Comment: This may be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636653/what-matrix-corresponds-to-the-sum-of-the-column-space-of-two-matrices-strang

Answer (score 0):

'Evaluating' $AX_1$, for all $X_1$ will give the column space of $A $, and similarly for $B$. The sum of these two will give the set of vectors $\{u+v\}$, wher $u,v $ are elements of column space of $A $ and clmn space of $B $ respectively. That is, we get the (algebraic) sum of the two subspaces (also a subspace). Considering the matrices as operators this is also obviously $Im (A)+Im (B) $.

Sum of such subspaces and similar have been  and are studied, and will be considered for example in operator theory. Books on Linear algebra may consider this and related questions.

Comment: Thanks, @AnyAD. I am not a mathematician, I asked this question as such combination appeared in my research. So, one sub-question, are there any necessary conditions on $A$ and $B$ (like positive definiteness, non-singularity etc) in operator theory?